# Error in code : Code has no effect

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

The following is my code. this code moves a text across the screen. I am doing a project which is to be submitted in school. Sadly, Our project must be done using Turbo C++ and not Visual Studio or CodeBlocks.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
    for(int fp=0, sp=getmaxx();fp <= (getmaxx()/4)-20, sp >= (getmaxx()/2)+60; fp++, sp--)
    {
        cleardevice();
        setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,RED);
        bar(320,50,340,170);
        bar(270,100,390,120);
        settextstyle(SCRIPT_FONT,HORIZ_DIR,5);
        outtextxy(fp-125,300,"Welcome To ");
        outtextxy(sp,300,"MedStore");
        delay(10);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler is showing an error

> The code has no effect

Can somebody please guide me in sorting out this error?

Comment: Why on earth are you using TurboC++?

Comment: @Archimaredes As i told you, i have to do my project in turbo c++ only. I normally use Visual Studio, but my college uses Turbo C++. Ergo, I need to use Turbo C++.

Comment: What I meant is - why on earth does your college use it?!

Comment: @Archimaredes  I have no idea! I have asked the college authorities to install Visual Studio or CodeBlocks, but they say that they will let the students use Turbo C++ only as TC++ is very easy to use.

Comment: In future, it would be very helpful if you could tell us *which line* the compiler said had no effect.  (Even the exact expression.)  Please include the full text of error messages.

Comment: Dude, you should certainly change your college

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the condition from the `for` loop:

```
fp<=(getmaxx()/4)-20,sp>=(getmaxx()/2)+60
```

The comma in the middle is the comma operator; it discards the result of the code to its left, and the result of the expression is simply the value of the expression to the right of the comma. That's what the compiler is **warning** you about (this is not, formally, an **error**; the code's meaning is well defined, and any compiler that refuses to compile it does not conform to the language definition). Change it to this:

```
fp<=(getmaxx()/4)-20 && sp>=(getmaxx()/2)+60
```

or to this:

```
fp<=(getmaxx()/4)-20 || sp>=(getmaxx()/2)+60
```

depending on what the code is actually supposed to do.